# Why Is Admob Interstitial Ad Not Showing On AndroidOS?

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

I apply the ad codes exactly as Google published, but the ad is not shown.

My codes:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
InterstitialAd.load( this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() { //test reklam id
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
        // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
        // an ad is loaded.
        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
        Log.i( TAG, "onAdLoaded" );
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
        // Handle the error
        Log.i( TAG, loadAdError.getMessage() );
        mInterstitialAd = null;
    }
});
```

Here is the button code I use to show the ad:

```
btnGo.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
            mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
            Log.e( "ads", "must be shown" );
        }
        startActivity( new Intent( MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class ) );
    }
});
```

When the ad is loaded, I get a loaded log about it, it seems like there is no problem.
I check if the ad is null for showing ad status, and I get an ad showing if it is not null, which is fine.
The only problem is that the ad isn't showing.

What could be the problem or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: My best guess is that you are calling startActivity before the ad get any time to be shown. Instead, you should implement onAdClosed in the load-logic and call startAtivity(secondActivity) there.

Comment: How is onAdClosed called? Can you help me? You just have onLoaded and onFailed.

Comment: thanx @AndreasEvjenth working for me your idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:

```
if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
    mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
    mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback(){
      @Override
      public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
        // Called when fullscreen content is dismissed.
    startActivity( new Intent( MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class ) );
        Log.d("TAG", "The ad was dismissed.");
      }

      @Override
      public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
        // Called when fullscreen content failed to show.
    startActivity( new Intent( MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class ) );
        Log.d("TAG", "The ad failed to show.");
      }

      @Override
      public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
        // Called when fullscreen content is shown.
        // Make sure to set your reference to null so you don't
        // show it a second time.
        mInterstitialAd = null;
        Log.d("TAG", "The ad was shown.");
      }
    });
} else {
    startActivity( new Intent( MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class ) );
                }
```